# How do I get rid of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in my code?

Tags: java, exception, stringindexoutofbounds

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I wanted to test myself and make a mini-programming language. But ever since I've decided to expand my code, I keep getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. I've done some research here on stackoverflow and on youtube, and it seems like I am having a specific issue. Can you check it out please?
Thank you in advance...
PS: Sorry for confusing variable names, I've named it in my native language :P
code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Komanda {
private String tip;
private String naziv;
private String parametar;
public Komanda() {
    super();
}
public Komanda(String tip, String parametar) {
    super();
    this.tip = tip;
    this.parametar = parametar;
}
public Komanda(String tip, String naziv, String parametar) {
    super();
    this.tip = tip;
    this.naziv = naziv;
    this.parametar = parametar;
}
public String getTip() {
    return tip;
}
public void setTip(String tip) {
    this.tip = tip;
}
public String getNaziv() {
    return naziv;
}
public void setNaziv(String naziv) {
    this.naziv = naziv;
}
public String getParametar() {
    return parametar;
}
public void setParametar(String parametar) {
    this.parametar = parametar;
}
}


public class Main {

public static void execute(Vector<Komanda> code) {
    for (int i = 0; i < code.size(); i++) {
        if (code.elementAt(i).getTip().equals("print:")) {
            if (!code.elementAt(i).getParametar().contains(":")) {
                System.out.println(code.elementAt(i).getParametar());
            } else {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print(code.elementAt(i).getParametar().substring(0,
                        code.elementAt(i).getParametar().indexOf(':') + 1));
                for (int k = 0; k < code.size(); i++) {
                    if (code.elementAt(k).getNaziv().equals(code.elementAt(i).getParametar()
                            .substring(code.elementAt(i).getParametar().indexOf(':') + 1))) {
                        System.out.print(" " + code.elementAt(k).getParametar());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (code.elementAt(i).getTip().equals("var")) {

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Vector<Komanda> code = new Vector<Komanda>();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("NNS 0.1 (v0.1.0:1, Oct  7 2017, 18:40:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit]");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1;) {

        String line = console.nextLine();
        Scanner lineRreader = new Scanner(line);
        if (lineRreader.next().equalsIgnoreCase("SLC;")) {
            code.removeAllElements();
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(';') + 2);
            if (line.equals("terminate")) {
                break;
            }
            if (lineRreader.next().equals("print:")) {
                System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf(':') + 2));
            }
            if (line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')).equals("print")) {
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1);
                int firstNumber = lineRreader.nextInt();
                char operation = lineRreader.next().charAt(0);
                int secondNumber = lineRreader.nextInt();
                System.out.print(firstNumber + " " + operation + " " + secondNumber);
                switch (operation) {
                case '+':
                    int a = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                    System.out.print(" = " + (int) a);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    int b = firstNumber - secondNumber;
                    System.out.print(" = " + (int) b);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    int c = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                    System.out.print(" = " + (int) c);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    double d = firstNumber / secondNumber;
                    System.out.print(" = " + (double) d);
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

        } else {
            if (line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')).equalsIgnoreCase("print: ")) { // THIS IS THE 72ND LINE
                code.add(new Komanda("print:", line.substring(line.indexOf(' ')+1)));
            }
            else if (line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')).equalsIgnoreCase("var")) {
                code.add(new Komanda("var", lineRreader.next(),
                        line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1, line.length())));
            }
            else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exec")) {
                execute(code);
            }

        }
        lineRreader.close();
    }
    console.close();
}

}
```

MY CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
NNS 0.1 (v0.1.0:1, Oct  7 2017, 18:40:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit] <--STATUS STRING
print: helloworld <---- ME TYPING PRINT: COMMAND
exec <---- THIS IS THE COMMAND THAT TRIGGERS THE EXCEPTION
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String 
index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

Comment: `at Main.main(Main.java:72)` tells us the error occurs at line 72. What line is that?

Comment: It's one of the `line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '))` lines; `line` doesn't contain a space.

Comment: If line doesn't have any blanck spaces, indexOf will return -1. That will throw indexoutofbounds exception when used in the substring method

Comment: guys, 'print: helloworld' is the line. As far as I can see, it contains ' '. Can you give me an example of what you are thinking of because I cannot seem to find it, thank you once again

Comment: From your question: "`exec <---- THIS IS THE COMMAND THAT TRIGGERS THE EXCEPTION`" Nope, no space there.

Comment: Note: `line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')).equalsIgnoreCase("print: ")` would never be true, because `line.indexOf(' ')` would find the space immediately after the `:`, thus the substring would extract `"print:"`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `execute` method, you have the inner for loop like following

```
for (int k = 0; k < code.size(); i++)
```

here you are incrementing `i` not `k`. And you are calling `substring` using `i`. I think the issue is here. Because the for loop will never end and eventually there will be a `i` value for which you get `indexOutOfBound`

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but even when I've fixed it, it still seems to not work.

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

> ```
> exec <---- THIS IS THE COMMAND THAT TRIGGERS THE EXCEPTION
> ```

You're getting the exception because you've got conditions like this:

```
if (line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')).equalsIgnoreCase("print: ")) {
  // ...
} else if (line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')).equalsIgnoreCase("var")) {
  // ...
} else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exec")) {
  // ...
}
```

Because `exec` doesn't contain a space, `line.indexOf(' ')` returns -1, and `line.substring(0, -1)` fails because the second parameter is negative. You don't reach the check for `exec` because it's after a check which throws an exception.

Move the `if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exec"))` to be checked before the conditions which require a space in them, e.g.

```
if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exec")) {
  // ...
} else if (line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')).equalsIgnoreCase("print: ")) {
  // ...
} else if (line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')).equalsIgnoreCase("var")) {
  // ...
}
```

Although you might want to extract the value of `line.indexOf(' ')` to a variable, and explicitly check this is non-negative, so you can avoid checking the conditions in the case that the line isn't `exec` and doesn't contain a space:

```
if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exec")) {
  // ...
} else {
  int spacePos = line.indexOf(' ');
  if (spacePos >= 0) {
    if (line.substring(0, spacePos).equalsIgnoreCase("print: ")) {
      // ...
    } else if (line.substring(0, spacePos).equalsIgnoreCase("var")) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note that you can make this less error-prone and more efficient by using `String.regionMatches`: this avoids the need to explicitly create a substring to check if `line` starts with a given string. That method itself is a bit cumbersome, but you can wrap it into a method:

```
static boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(String line, String cmd) {
  return line.regionMatches(
      true         /* ignore case */,
      0            /* from start of line */,
      cmd          /* the thing you're searching for */,
      0            /* from start of cmd */,
      cmd.length() /* all of cmd */);
}
```

Now you can keep the original ordering of the conditions:

```
// Extra space appended because you were searching for the space after the command.
if (startsWithIgnoreCase(line, "print: " + " ")) {
  // ...
} else if (startsWithIgnoreCase(line, "var" + " ")) {
  // ...
} else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exec")) {
  // ...
}
```